# Jquery Slideshow Animations Behaving Strangely (events firing, building up in queue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a very simple slideshow.

I would like the slideshow to pause on hover and resume when the user moves their mouse off the slideshow (`#slide_container`). While the slideshow works fine, and so does the hover (to an extent), if I flick my mouse on and off the slideshow repeatedly, it completely messes the slide and starts animating sporadically (check the fiddle below to see what I mean).

I tried adding `promise`, so that before animating it completes any queued animation, but despite this, the behaviour remains.

How should I go about fixing this?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hR6wZ/

my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //get variables

    var slide_width      = $('.slider_container').width();
    var number_of_slides = $('.slider_container .slide').length;
    var slider_width = slide_width*number_of_slides;

    //set element dimensions
    $('.slide').width(slide_width);
    $('.slider').width(slider_width);

    var i = 0;

    var hover_switch = 0;

    $('.slider_container').hover(function() { 
        //Hover mode on
        hover_switch = 1;
    }, function() {
        //Hover mode off
        hover_switch = 0;
        sliderLoop()
    });

    function animateSlider() {
        $(":animated").promise().done(function() {
            $('.slider').finish().animate({ marginLeft: -(slide_width * i) });
        });
    }

    function sliderLoop() {
        setTimeout(function(){          
            //Only runs if hover mode is off;
            if(i < number_of_slides-1 && !hover_switch) {
                i++;
                animateSlider();
                sliderLoop();
            }
            else if (!hover_switch)
            {
                i = 0;
                animateSlider();
                sliderLoop()
            }
        },4000);


    }

    sliderLoop();


});
```

EDIT: also I did try using stop instead of `finish()` but this didn't fix the issue..

Comment: can you explain your problem in more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Becuase your calling the slider loop each time you hover out everytime even if you hover back and forth like ten times it tells it and queus it up to animate the x amount of times you did that.

What you can try is Only have the slider loop check right then and their when it's about to animate if it is being hovered or not and don't call the slider loop from the every time that it hovers out.
Another way is right before it begins animating set a variable for the duration of the animation to tell it not to call the animateSlider function if Currently_animating
so add  && !currently_animating to each if statement within the sliderloop function.
That method however will help but probably the first way would be better as then it will never animate more then every x miliseconds or however long you set it to be.

But in General you probably should not call the sliderloop function if hover_switch = 0 becuase then it will just queue up the slider loop each time you hover out.